# Waterfall display

Tags: image, scroll, waterfall

I need help in creating a waterfall display of my image data stored in a buffer. The stream of image data needs to be displayed scrolling down the screen as its being acquired from the camera.
I am using visual studio c++ windows forms.
Can someone please help me to figure out how to achieve this display?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the info you provide is to minimal to suggest anything worthwhile.

For making custom graphical effects, the usual suggested route is to make a DIB bitmap, which gives you access to the raw bytes. Alter the bytes anyway you see fit (adding the stream of raw image bytes from your camera) and then blit it to the windows HDC in a timely fashion.

Comment: waterfall display refers to displaying acquired data scrolling down the screen. It looks like a waterfall(as the name suggests)

I tried using bitmap class(with picture box control) to display the acquired data in a timely fashion as you said. But as there is a time delay,the scrolling display is not smooth. Do you know how to display the acquired images smoothly(like a scrolling video)?

Comment: use a better timer function. The standard windows timer doesn't go faster than 50 or 100 MS.  use the multimedia timer for faster callbacks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712704(VS.85).aspx